# Function is not defined, don't know why

Tags: javascript, function

Here's the code. Button1 and button2 come up as undefined.

```
$('.game_time').each(function() {
   //   bind_toggle($(this).find('a.preview_tweets.selected'), $(this).find('.with_tweets'),
    //      $(this).find('a.collapse_tweets'), $(this).find('.without_tweets')); 

  button1.click = function() {
        if ($(this).find('a.preview_tweets.selected').hasClass('open')){
        } else {
            if ($(this).find('a.preview_tweets.selected').length == 0) {
                get_preview_tweets('<%= game.away_team.url %>,<%= game.home_team.url %>', 
            3, '<%= game.id %>');
            }
            $(this).find('a.preview_tweets.selected').show()
            $(this).find('a.preview_tweets.selected').addClass('open');
        }
   }

   button2.click = function() {
        if ($(this).find('a.preview_tweets.selected').hasClass('open')){
            $(this).find('a.preview_tweets.selected').hide();
        } else {
            }
   }
});
```

I'm entirely new to Javascript, so if there's some blaringly obvious thing, I'm sorry.

Comment: Where are `button1` and `button2` declared?

Comment: look pretty undefined to me here as well

Comment: `var button1 = $('#button1');`, maybe?

Comment: If `button1` is an element, instead of `button1.click`, use `$('#button1').click`

Comment: button1 and button2 are declared, as an anchored class, in anther html doctument. Button1 should be 'preview_tweets,' and button2 'collapse_tweets'

Comment: You mean like `<a name='button1'>`? And what do you mean when you say what the buttons "should be"?

Answer (score 0):

```
button1.click = function() {}
```

This would be called like so: `button1.click()`

You can change it to just button1 if you like

```
button1 = function() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using jQuery. Are those the `id`s of the button you're trying to reference? If so, try `$("#button1").click`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 buttons on the page with id button1 and button2 then you can just use:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    //Your code here
});
```